# Step by step method for $\int\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}\,dx$$

What is the step-by-step way of solving this integral problem?
I tried using substitution which was $x^2-1=t^2$, but end up with an even more complicated equation.
Substituting trigonometric functions for example :$x^2=\sec^2(a)$ so that $x^2-1$ part becomes $\tan^2(a)$ did not help either.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far could you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: Better use a calculator that gives all the steps.

Comment: When one learns partial fraction decompositions, one must have seen step-by-step examples. Have you seen *any* such examples?

Comment: $$\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}= 1+\frac1{x-1}-\frac1{x+1}$$

Comment: @Quanto Thanks. this is what I was searching for

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}
\int\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}\,\mathrm dx&=\int\frac{x^2-1+2}{x^2-1}\,\mathrm dx\\[1ex]
&=\int\left(1+\frac2{x^2-1}\right)\,\mathrm dx
\end{align}$$

To integrate the second term, you can split it into partial fractions to get the expression mentioned in the comments, or make a substitution $x=\sec t$ and $\mathrm dx=\sec t\tan t\,\mathrm dt$. Then

$$\begin{align}
\int\left(1+\frac2{x^2-1}\right)\,\mathrm dx&=x+2\int\frac{\sec t\tan t}{\sec^2t-1}\,\mathrm dt\\[1ex]
&=x+2\int\csc t\,\mathrm dt\\[1ex]
&=x-2\ln|\csc t+\cot t|+C\\[1ex]
&=x-2\ln\left|\csc(\sec^{-1}x)+\cot(\sec^{-1}x)\right|+C\\[1ex]
&=x-2\ln\left|\frac x{\sqrt{x^2-1}}+\frac1{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right|+C
\end{align}$$

With some massaging you can get this in a simpler form that immediately agrees with the partial-fraction-decomposition result:

$$x+\ln|x-1|-\ln|x+1|+C$$

Comment: thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2):

This can be evaluated using partial fraction decomposition. Observe how

$$\begin{align*}\frac {x^2+1}{x^2-1} & =\frac {x^2-1+2}{x^2-1}\\ & =1+\frac 2{x^2-1}\end{align*}$$

The final fraction can be broken down by assuming the partial fractions follow the form

$$\frac 2{(x+1)(x-1)}=\frac A{x+1}+\frac B{x-1}$$

Multiplying both sides by $(x+1)(x-1)$ and setting $x=\pm1$ gives $A=-B=-1$. Or, in other words,

$$\frac {x^2+1}{x^2-1}=1+\frac 1{x-1}-\frac 1{x+1}$$

Integrate piece by piece to get

$$\int\mathrm dx\,\frac {x^2+1}{x^2-1}\color{blue}{=x+\log(x-1)-\log(x+1)+C}$$